# MySQL - Combining INSERT, VALUES, and SELECT?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm kind of new to SQL, and I'm really only interacting with it enough to get a high score database working.  I'm using a php script to access my online MySQL db.  Anyways.

What I have is 2 tables, Player and Score.  Player has an id, uniqueDeviceId, and chosenname.
Score has the usual things youd expect.

What I'd really like to do in a single query (to reduce complexity...) is to combine the syntaxes of

```
INSERT INTO scores VALUES
and INSERT INTO scores SELECT...
```

Into some sort of monster, like

```
INSERT INTO scores(score,difficulty,playerid)
   VALUES(TheScoreThatImProviding,TheDifficultyThatImProviding, (SELECT 
       id FROM player WHERE uniqueDeviceId = TheUniqueIdThatImProviding)
     )
```

If that makes sense.  I want to lookup the playerId (3rd "value"), and mix the result of that select with the input of the VALUES provided.

Is this possible?  All the googling results ive found either have it all VALUES or all SELECT.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Makes sense and is called [INSERT SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html). This is an example query for the uniqueDeviceId 123, Score 5 and Difficulty 'easy':

```
INSERT INTO scores (score, difficulty, playerid)
  SELECT 5, 'easy', id
  FROM player WHERE uniqueDeviceId = 123;
```

Comment: So I can just say in the SELECT part the hard-coded values, and it's not going to be looking for a column named that when it searches the player table?

Comment: Numbers are directly passed through without looking for columns. Strings also.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you very much.  I just tested that syntax and it does indeed work.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) you're close.  But put all the values into your select.  Something like:

```
insert into scores (score, difficulty, playerid )
    select TheScoreThatImProviding, TheDifficultyThatImProviding, player.id 
      from player where uniqueDeviceId = TheUniqueIdThatImProviding
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach:

```
INSERT INTO `tableA` SET 
           columnA =  (SELECT `columnY` FROM `tableY` WHERE `id` = 2), 
           columnB =  (SELECT `columnZ` FROM `tableB` WHERE `id` = 3);
```

I didn't benchmarked it yet. But using multiple `SELECT` statements will burden the Database server. The plus side of this approach is the readability.