# MySQL INSERT [...] SELECT with mixed data (from SELECT clause and hand-inserted values)?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, opencart

I'm trying to modify a table from OpenCart, a PHP-based e-cart solution. I currently have the **oc_product_to_store** table populated with the 1300+ product catalog we currently offer. We created a second store and I want to update that table for every **product_id** to have a second row pointing to the second store (so, in practical reality, I want to insert the **1** value into the **store_id** field for each new row, while preserving the **product_id** value).

My question is: is it doable in a single query? Something ala **INSERT [...] SELECT** where I get the **product_id** field through the query and specifying the **store_id** 'manually' at the same time?

Or maybe I should try a **LOOP** instead?

I'm scratching my head a bit, but I find it a bit difficult. Any hint?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it in [here][1]

Thanks anyway :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091707/mysql-combining-insert-values-and-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you mean?

```
 INSERT oc_product_to_store (productid, storeid)
 SELECT productid, 2
 FROM oc_product_to_store 
 WHERE storedid=1
```

(where 1 is your existing store , and 2 is your new store)

Comment: Thanks, I found an even simpler solution (as all products were just belonging to the first store, a **INSERT INTO oc_product_to_store (`product_id`,`store_id`) SELECT product_id, 1 FROM oc_product_to_store;** did wonders) :)