# MySql Insert Dynamic Query with Nested Select

Tags: mysql, dynamic, insert, inner-join, sql-insert

I'm trying a MySQL Insert Query with mix of static & Dynamic Values. The INSERT command is.

```
    INSERT INTO ebdb.requestaction(RequestID,
                                   ActionID,
                                   TransactionID,
                                   IsActive,
                                   IsComplete)
       VALUES (
                 1,
**Dynamic Value from Below Query,
Dynamic Value from Below Query,**
                1,
                 0);
```

The Query to fetch the field 2 & 3 come from the below Query.

```
    SELECT transitionaction.TransitionID, transitionaction.ActionID
      FROM transitionaction
           INNER JOIN transition
              ON transitionaction.TransitionID = transition.TransitionID
     WHERE     transition.TenantID = 1
           AND transition.ProcessID = 1
           AND transition.CurrentStateID = 1
    ORDER BY transitionaction.TransitionID;
```

I'm doing something wrong in here.
Please guide me as to how this can be achieved in the most optimized way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Combining INSERT, VALUES, and SELECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091707/mysql-combining-insert-values-and-select)

Answer (score 0):

You can select static values as part of a query, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO ebdb.requestaction(RequestID, ActionID, TransactionID, IsActive, IsComplete)
SELECT 1, transitionaction.ActionID, transitionaction.TransitionID, 1, 0
  FROM transitionaction
       INNER JOIN transition
          ON transitionaction.TransitionID = transition.TransitionID
 WHERE     transition.TenantID = 1
       AND transition.ProcessID = 1
       AND transition.CurrentStateID = 1
ORDER BY transitionaction.TransitionID;
```

For more information, refer to [MySQL's Insert...Select Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)